# transfer value to entry form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am newbie with PHP and Jquery. Please help me for this problem.
I have a table contain data, which retrieved from database in php and mysql. I have a checkbox for each row. I also had a editted form, which will be appear when I click to "Edit" button after choose a checkbox in table.
Now I want to display current value on select boxes in editted form when I click into "Edit".
How will I do?
Below is my code:
HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="edit_permission" class="btn btn-app" id="edit_permission"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>

 <div class="entry-form" id="newdb-entryform">
      <form action="" method="post" name="new_item" class="form-inline" id="new_item">
            <p >Add Permission </p>
                <select id="newlevel" name="newlevel">
                    <option value="">Choose level</option>
                    <?php
                        $sql="SELECT level
                              FROM  level";
                        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option value='$row[level]'";
                        $temp='';
                        if(isset($_POST['newlevel'])) { $temp=$_POST['newlevel'];}
                        if($temp == $row['level']) { echo "selected='selected'";}

                        echo ">$row[level]</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select><span class="error">*</span>
                <select id="newdatabase" name="newdatabase">
                    <option value="">Choose system</option>
                    <?php
                        $sql="SELECT `database` FROM `database`";
                        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option value='$row[database]'";
                        $temp='';
                        if(isset($_POST['newdatabase'])) { $temp=$_POST['newdatabase'];}
                        if($temp == $row['database']) { echo "selected='selected'";}

                        echo ">$row[database]</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select><span class="error">*</span>

            <input type="hidden" name="id_edit" id="id_edit">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" id="save" />

            <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancelupload" id="cancel"/>
      </form>
  </div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#edit_permission").click(function(){ 
        if ($("#user_form input:checkbox:checked").length==1){
            $('#newdb-entryform p').text('Update permission');
            $('#dbname').attr("placeholder", "Input new database");

            vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
            console.log(vals);
            $('#id_db').val(vals);
            $("#newdb-entryform").fadeIn("fast");   
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $("#text-danger-message").text('Choose one item to edit!');
                $("#danger-alert").fadeTo(4000,50).fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $("#danger-alert").alert('close');
                });     
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Please help me. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you realize you have two buttons with `type="submit"`?  Also, please don't put queries in the middle of your select boxes. Assign the results to a variable and then reference the variable in your `<select>` element.

I realize you're new at this so take this as constructive criticism. Also, please try to make your question a little more precise.

Answer (score 0):

See This Example.. For Useful ?..

1 ) https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html
2 ) https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your queries before html.And query results have loop , using loops you can get your data in select boxes like below.

```
<select id="newlevel" name="newlevel">
     <option value="">Choose level</option>
     <?php foreach ($result as $value) { ?>
           <option value=<?php echo $value['level'];?> <?php (isset($_POST['newlevel'])) : echo "selected" ? ""; ?>><?php echo $value['level'];?>
           </option>
     <?php } ?>
</select><span class="error">*</span>
```

NOTE : This is just an example.Just understand this code and apply as you needed.